# Why isn't the threadpooltest running correctly?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-7

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/ThreadPoolTest.htm

I downloaded the source code from the official website, but can't get the code running for some reason. I have JCreator 5.0 and the latest java.

--------------------Configuration: --------------------

Tests the ThreadPool task.
Usage: java ThreadPoolTest numTasks numThreads
  numTasks - integer: number of task to run.
  numThreads - integer: number of threads in the thread pool.

Process completed.

Is it because the code is not compatible with Java 7?

How come?

Is there a way to use Java 6 without uninstalling Java 7?

Comment: *Is there way to use Java 6 without uninstalling Java 7?* yes just point to Java 6. Change the path.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the Java version.

Comment: Look at the code! It is expecting 2 cmd params.

Comment: I see no problems.  Are you running it with java ThreadPoolTest <some number> <some other number>?  It compiles and runs *fine* with Java 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code need two parameters to run. And it returns if there are not 2 parameters.

```
if (args.length != 2) {
  System.out.println("Tests the ThreadPool task.");
  System.out
      .println("Usage: java ThreadPoolTest numTasks numThreads");
  System.out.println("  numTasks - integer: number of task to run.");
  System.out.println("  numThreads - integer: number of threads "
      + "in the thread pool.");
  return;
}
```

Just replace this part or give your programm the two parameters.

Comment: How would you enter the parameters? I thought I had to enable "Prompt for main method arguments", but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know how to set commandline parameters in JCreator (never used it) but you can start you jar via commandline. Type: "java -jar YourJarName.jar <arg1> <arg2>"

Comment: If you don't want to use commandline arguments just replace it in code. Remove "args[0]" and "args[1]" and replace it with fixed numbers. Then you can remove the code above.

Comment: i changed the lines to: int numTasks = 4;
        int numThreads = 6; but it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: this doesn't work either: int numTasks = Integer.parseInt("6");
        int numThreads = Integer.parseInt("7");

Comment: have you removed the code above? the if block i posted needs to be removed then.